# Make 3 separate tables, or 1 combined table for similar data?

Tags: table, database-design, design-pattern

When designing a database's structure, if we have multiple tables with similar data, should these tables be combined, with an added `ENUM` field to denote the table type; or should 3 separate tables be created?

E.g.

- VAT (sales tax) rates
- National Minimum Wage rates
- Currency exchange rates

The structure of the tables would be:

```
|============= VAT rates =============|
| id | rate |    from    |     to     |
|----|------|------------|------------|
| 1  | 17.5 | 1991-04-01 | 2008-11-30 |
| 2  | 15.0 | 2008-12-01 | 2009-12-31 |
| 3  | 17.5 | 2010-01-01 | 2011-01-03 |
| 4  | 20.0 | 2011-01-04 |    NULL    |
|=====================================|
```

All 3 tables are frequently referenced by queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full keys to your data are more complex that you indicate.  Sales tax rates can vary by jurisdiction and goods can be categorised as luxury or exempt. Wage rates can vary by industry and public holiday / normal work day.  Exchange rates have to be keyed on the source and destination currencies.

While your values may all be fractional numbers they have different *units*, which makes them different *things*.  Tax is "percentage", wages are "dollars per hour", ForEx rates are dimensionless ratios.

Your data scope my be constrained to eliminate these considerations, of course.  Only you can say.

Joe Celko covers this topic in depth [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/).

Comment: In this particular case, there is only 1 sales tax (in the UK), only 1 National Minimum Wage (for over 18's), and all exchange rates are based upon a single source currency. Does this change anything?

Comment: The all-in-one is a borderline anti-pattern. See Celko's article. You can always start with one table and re-write when your requirements grow. As long as you understand the compromises and costs you are incurring either way that's the main thing.  I've written system's both ways and can't get all fundamentalist either way.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer, I'm gonna go ahead and make separate tables; in case the requirements later expand to include attributes like you mentioned.

Comment: Forex rates are not dimensionless. The dimension of cable for example, is USD/GBP